# Uso de dois Onsubmit no JavaScript e Função If dentro de um alert

Tags: javascript, html, validação

estou treinando `JavaScript` com `HTML` e `CSS` e estou criando uma página simples de web onde irei fazer o calculo de IMC.O meu usuário além de informar seu peso e altura,devera informar seus dados:nome,e-mail,telefone..

Através do `JavaScript` devo realizar os cálculos do IMC e validar tanto o nome quanto o E-Mail do usuário, tenho um exemplo que estou seguindo, porém tem um comando que não estou entendendo direito : `ONSUBMIT`

```html
  <section class="userinfo">
      <form class="info" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validateName()">
        <ul>
          <li><label for="nome">Nome:</label>
              <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome" id="name" required/></li>
          <li><label for="email">E-mail:</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu E-mail" id="email" required></li>
          <li><label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
              <input type="tel" name="telefone" placeholder="(xx)xxxxx-xxxx" id="telefone"/></li>
```

No campo do `Form` eu não teria que informar dois `onsubmit` ? Um validateName e outro validateEmail?

A minha segunda dúvida é sobre o funcionamento do `JavaScript`

```js
function validateName(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var nameValidator = /^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöüúçñ' ]{5,}$/i;

  if (!nameValidator.test(name)){
    alert("Nome invalido")
    return false}
}
```

Esse `!if` siginifica o operador lógico `não` correto? Minha dúvida na verdade é na condição

> nameValidator.test(name)

Esse `namevalidator`, não teria que ser chamado de : `validateName` ,que é a minha função para validação do nome do meu usuário?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"No campo do Form eu não teria que informar dois onsubmit ? Um validateName e outro validateEmail?"*

No `form`, o evento `onsubmit` é um evento que acontece quanto tenta "submter" o formulário, ou seja, por exemplo quando clica num botão `submit`. Então você pode executar uma ou mais *functions*, pode fazer todas as validações que deseja.
Finalmente, pode retornar `true` ou `false` conforme suas validações para que prossiga ou não o submit. Veja o exemplo:

```
<form class="info" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

function validateForm() {
   var ok = validateName();
   if (ok) {
      ok = validateEmail();
   }

   return true;
}
```

Nesse caso, a *function* "validateForm" executa as duas validações que você mencionou, sendo que cada uma delas deve retornar `true` ou `false`.
No código use o `if (ok)` para verificar se a primeira validação retornou `true` para fazer a segunda. Se a primeira já retornou `false` nem executa a segunda.
Mas você pode preferir executar a segunda para exibir alguma mensagem, é só uma forma de simplificar como sugestão.

*"Esse !if siginifica o operador lógico não correto?"*
Exatamente, significa "se não".

*"Esse namevalidator, não teria que ser chamado de : validateName ,que é a minha função para validação do nome do meu usuário?"*
Nesse caso `nameValidator` é uma variável que contem uma *Regular Expression*, algo que vai validar o formato do nome, que não precisa ter o mesmo nome da *function*

Mais sobre expressões regulares: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

**EDIT**: aqui uma sugestão de unificar a validação e um único método:

```
function validateForm(){
  // primeiro o nome:
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var nameValidator = /^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöüúçñ' ]{5,}$/i;

  if (!nameValidator.test(name)){
    alert("Nome inválido");
    return false;
  }

  // Depois email:
  var emmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var emailValidator = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;

  if (!emailValidator.test(email)){
    alert("Email inválido");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Então tenho que ter dois onsubmits de qualquer maneira correto?pois tendo só o do nome,ele so ira submeter esse campo?

Comment: e mais uma dúvida,function validateForm() {
   var ok = validateName();
   if (ok) {
      ok = validateEmail();
   }

   return ok;     Dentro desse if estarei validando os dois campos? ou apenas o email? Pois não entendi muito bem pq a variavel nome esta fora do if e a variavel email esta dentro!

Comment: @CarolM, na função `validateName()` já está validando no nome como no seu exemplo, precisa só criar o código da função `validateEmail()`. Coloquei assim para responder exatamente como você perguntou, mas para simplificar você pode fazer as duas validações dentro da função `validateForm`, acho que fica mais fácil e claro

Comment: coloquei um exemplo na resposta da ideia de validar tudo numa única *function*

Comment: agora ficou mais fácil ainda para entender!
Muito obrigada pela ajuda Ricardo!

Answer (score 1):

O evento `onSubmit` do JavaScript é uma ótima forma de se automatizar tarefas. Com ele, você pode fazer o navegador validar as informações que foram enviadas através de um formulário antes que o servidor as receba.

o evento `onSubmit` executa uma série de comandos (ou apenas um) no momento em que o visitante de um site clica no botão de envio de um formulário.

**Exemplo**

> Obs: retirei o `required` e coloquei email `type text` para facilitar a verificação

```js
function validat(){
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var nameValidator = /^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöüúçñ' ]{5,}$/i;

   if (!nameValidator.test(name)){
     console.log("Nome invalido")
     return false
   }
        
var stremail= document.getElementById('email').value;

   if( stremail=="" || stremail.indexOf('@')==-1 || stremail.indexOf('.')==-1 ){
     console.log( "Por favor, informe um E-MAIL válido!" );
     return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<form class="info" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest" method="post" onsubmit="return validat()">
<ul>
    <li><label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome" id="name"/></li>
    <li><label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu E-mail" id="email"></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Validar">
</form>
```